# Skipped rows or rows read multiple times with NOLOCK

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, nolock

Is it possible to stimulate a situation where rows either get skipped or get read multiple times in a select statement? E.g. the way we can cause a blocking or a deadlock...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gail Shaw posted [a demo of how to do so](http://source.entelect.co.za/the-effects-of-the-nolock-hint) quite a while ago. It works by inducing row movement by increasing the size of the row over time. No inserts or deletes, just updates to existing records.